# Does uClibc support using pthreads?

Tags: embedded, multithreading, buildroot

I recently attended an embedded Linux course that stated that uClibc does not support the use of `pthreads` and that it only supports `linuxthreads`. Furthermore, the course instructor implied that `linuxthreads` were next to useless. However, when reading a number of online articles, the implication is that they are in fact supported. Furthermore, when building a root file system and kernel image for a target embedded device using buildroot, I can see that I have `libpthread-0.9.33.2.so` and `libpthread.so.0` files in the `/lib` directory of my target root file system. I am really confused about the nature of the conflicting information I have received and would be very grateful if anyone could actually clarify the situation for me.

Comment: Look at the project's website? It is open source, after all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with version 0.9.32 (released 8 june 2011), uClibc is supporting NPTL for the following architectures: arm, i386, mips, powerpc, sh, sh64, x86_64.

Actually, both are an implementation of pthreads and will provide libpthread.so.